# layer masksToBounds default value not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, layer

I have next code;

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.tableView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.5f);
self.tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = .5f;
self.tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5f;
```

in description on property `masksToBounds` is writing that default is NO. But if I don't right in code it explicitly, shadow not appear. Why default value (NO) not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the tableView's `ScrollView` also has the property set.